# VMware Server 2.0.2 and Firefox 3.6 RC1

Tags: linux, vmware-server

it seems that VMware Server 2.0.2 and Firefox 3.6 RC1 don't like each other.

I have a reproducible problem on different networks, each with same software configuration (FF3.6 RC1 and VMware Server 2.0.2 on Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS 64bit).

The login screen doesn't show up and the Firefox remarks and non loadable page. It cannot load the page at all. The redirect is done (from http://***:8222 to https://***:8333 )

Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Disable use TLS v1 on the encryption tab of the advanced section of preferences. Under the network tab of the advanced section, change the size of the cache from 50mb to 0. Now refresh the login page. Keep refreshing it until the login shows up - sometimes it just doesn't load, but repeatedly refreshing gets it to load eventually.  I held down f5 at one point in chrome and it refreshed 20 or so times then popped up the login.

Comment: just disabling the TLSv1 did it for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the server does not serve the javascript files used on the page well all the time. Changing the size of cache to 0 and CTRL+F5 reloading worked for me after about 1 minute of reloads.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with older versions of Firefox as well, which makes me think it's not a Firefox problem but a VMware one.  The solution that works for me most of the time is to hold down ctrl and shift, and click the reload button a dozen or so times.  This will open a new tab for each reload, and hopefully one of them will show the login screen.

I think it's a race condition in the loading of javascript libraries from the management console.  There are a lot of reports in VMware communities about this, and no real solutions.